# Using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker for uploading to youtube channel, Access is Denied exception error on azure , works fine on local

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, youtube-api

I am working on app to upload video to youtube via an Azure App service. I am using this code to authenticate user

```
   UserCredential credential;
    ClientSecrets secret = new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "Client_id",
        ClientSecret = "Client_secret"
    };
        //Folder Path
        var folder = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Videos/");
        //Authenticate the user
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                secret,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
               Environment.UserName,
                CancellationToken.None,
                 new FileDataStore(folder + "folder")
            ).Result;

        // Initialize youtube service against authenticated user 

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });
```

This is working fine and video is uploaded when i test it on my local system but gives and exception "One or more errors occurred " when i publish the site to azure.Inner exception says "Access is denied" and stack trace is

```
     at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
```

I have write permissions to the path as i am storing the videos there.Spent almost 2 days playing around with Filedatastore etc but no success.
Please help

Comment: You may want to check these [guidelines](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/910449/troubleshooting-common-permissions-and-security-related-issues-in-asp.net) in troubleshooting common permissions and security-related issues in ASP.NET specifically on issues that occurs because of missing permissions and see if it will help you.

Comment: The client library is trying to spawn a new web browser on the azure server which is not allowed.